# How to get weeks/ days/ hours/ minutes ago from custom date & time "from now" in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a date & time format: `2019-11-25 09:49:19`. How can we compare this from current date & time and can display like: `3 days ago` or `weeks/ hours/ min ago`

Comment: try [react-native-timeago](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-timeago)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After many hit and trails I found exact solution:

`moment.utc("2019-12-04 12:00:24").local().startOf('seconds').fromNow()`

Output be like:

30 minutes ago

1 hour ago

2 weeks ago

Comment: Thanks, short and simple. I was using epoch time so just had to replace `utc` to `unix`

Comment: As of 2022 Moment is a legacy project, now in maintenance mode. You probably can use dayjs. It is a drop-in replacement of moment.

Comment: @Saif71 could this be done with react-date-object ?

Answer (score 5):

Install moment module

```
npm install moment
```

Then, you can find the time ago using the following code (replace time you want to convert with `created_at`) .

```
import moment from 'moment';
const dateTimeAgo = moment(new Date(created_at)).fromNow();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `moment.js` library. [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

```
moment("20111031", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(); // 8 years ago
moment("20120620", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(); // 7 years ago
moment().startOf('day').fromNow();        // 16 hours ago
moment().endOf('day').fromNow();          // in 8 hours
moment().startOf('hour').fromNow();       // an hour ago
```

Comment: It returns from date only which i YYYYMMDD. I need it with date and time.

Comment: Well moment.js doesnt support such need, but maybe you can use `CalendarTime` and display it like`Today at 2:30 AM` https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/ @LuvnishMonga

Answer (score 2):

Currently you can solve your question using `moment`. But I provide you some code of VainillaJS to solve your issue too.

```
const DAYS_OF_WEEK = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
const MONTHS_OF_YEAR = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

const daysBetween = (date1, date2) => {
  const ONE_DAY_ON_SECONDS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  const date1Ms = date1.getTime();
  const date2Ms = date2.getTime();

  const differenceMs = date2Ms - date1Ms;
  return Math.round(differenceMs / ONE_DAY_ON_SECONDS); 
}

const getHoursFromDate = (date) => {
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
  return hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
}

const dateFromNow = (date) => {
  const currentDate = new Date();

  if(date.getUTCDate() === currentDate.getUTCDate() && date.getUTCMonth() === currentDate.getUTCMonth() && date.getUTCFullYear() === currentDate.getUTCFullYear()) {
    const hours = Math.floor(Math.abs(date - currentDate) / 36e5);

    if (hours === 0) {
      const minutes = Math.round(((Math.abs(date - currentDate) % 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000);
      return minutes <= 1 ? 'A while ago' : `${minutes} minutes ago.`
    } else {
      return `${Math.floor(hours)} hours ago`;
    }
  } else {
    if (date.getUTCFullYear() < currentDate.getUTCFullYear() || daysBetween(date, currentDate) > 6) {
      return `${date.getDate()}/${MONTHS_OF_YEAR[date.getMonth()]} /${date.getFullYear()}`;
    } else {
      return `${DAYS_OF_WEEK[date.getDay()]} at ${getHoursFromDate(date)}`;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As of 2022 `Moment` is a legacy project, now in maintenance mode. You probably can use `dayjs`. It is a drop-in replacement of `moment`.

```
npm install dayjs
```

and then

```
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import relativeTime from "dayjs/plugin/relativeTime";
import localeEn from "dayjs/locale/en"; // With a custom alias for the locale object



 const daysago = (postDate) => { 
        dayjs.extend(relativeTime).locale(localeEn) 
        var fromNowOn = dayjs(postDate).fromNow(); 
        return(fromNowOn)
     };


{daysago("2022-11-07T09:50:00"")}
```

Comment: its localeEn not localeBn

Answer (score 1):

You can use `npm i moment` package from npm and use the diff function as below:
`moment.duration(nowMoment.diff(updateMoment)).as("hours")`.

Difference can be calculated in terms of days, hours or minutes.

Answer (score 1):

`https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/`

- If the range is exceeded, it will bubble up to other weeks.

```js
moment().day(-7); // last Sunday (0 - 7)
moment().day(0); // this Sunday (0)
moment().day(7); // next Sunday (0 + 7)
moment().day(10); // next Wednesday (3 + 7)
moment().day(24); // 3 Wednesdays from now (3 + 7 + 7 + 7)
```

- Gets or sets the day of the week according to the locale.

If the locale assigns Monday as the first day of the week, moment().weekday(0) will be Monday. If Sunday is the first day of the week, moment().weekday(0) will be Sunday.

#### As with moment#day, if the range is exceeded, it will bubble up to other weeks.

```js
// when Monday is the first day of the week
moment().weekday(-7); // last Monday
moment().weekday(7); // next Monday
// when Sunday is the first day of the week
moment().weekday(-7); // last Sunday
moment().weekday(7); // next Sunday
```

Comment: I appreciate with your answer but requirement is like : 10 min ago/ 4hours ago/ 1 day ago/ 2 weeks ago.

Answer (score 1):

This is function i used in my app.Don't need any of the libraries

```
export const findDaysDiffrent = (fromDate) => {

let CreatedDate = new Date(fromDate)
let today = new Date()
let requiredDiffrentDays

const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
const diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((CreatedDate - today) / oneDay));

if (diffDays >= 360) {
    requiredDiffrentDays = Math.floor(diffDays / 360) == 1 ? `${Math.floor(diffDays / 365)} year ago` : `${Math.floor(diffDays / 365)} years ago`
} else if (diffDays >= 30) {
    requiredDiffrentDays = Math.floor(diffDays / 30) == 1 ? `${Math.floor(diffDays / 30)} month ago` : `${Math.floor(diffDays / 30)} months ago`
} else if (diffDays < 30) {
    requiredDiffrentDays = (diffDays == 1 || diffDays == 0) ? `${diffDays} day ago` : `${diffDays} days ago`
}

return requiredDiffrentDays;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**react-time-ago**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-time-ago

react-time-ago does exactly what you want and more straight out of the box

`<ReactTimeAgo date={createdAt} />`

Key features that made me happy:

- Will auto convert future dates to "in 5 minutes"
- Provides a tooltip with the full date string
- Works with minimal setup (had it working in 2 minutes)

[image: Image shows the react-time-ago component with the tooltip below]